# TinyMCE installation gives warning

Tags: django, tinymce, django-grappelli, django-tinymce

I did pip install django-tinymce and it gives this warning

```
  Downloading django-tinymce-1.5.1.tar.gz (2.4MB): 2.4MB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package django-tinymce

    warning: no previously-included files found matching '*.pyc'
Installing collected packages: django-tinymce
  Running setup.py install for django-tinymce

    warning: no previously-included files found matching '*.pyc'
Successfully installed django-tinymce
Cleaning up...
```

1. What does this error means

I have have also installed Grappelli and its documentation says TinyMCE comes with it by default.

1. So, was pip install django-tinymce unnecessary on my part
2. The Grappelli documentation doesn't give proper explanation to use it. Can someone gives proper steps to configure tinyMCE

Also when I did python manage.py schemamigration --auto added_tinymce
I got this error

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'widget'
```

so can someone please guide me through it